# Python reading text files for calculation

Tags: python

I have hundreds of *.txt files that I need to open. Each text file have 4 coordinates (x    y):

```
401 353
574 236
585 260
414 376
```

I need to read each of them for simple calculation. What I have so far is:

```
import sys,os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        path = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        path = os.getcwd() + '/'
    try:
        filt = set([".txt", ".TXT"])

        sortlist = []
        sortlist = os.listdir(path)
        sortlist.sort()

        for item in sortlist:
            fileType = item[-4:]
            if fileType in filt:
                CurrentFile = open(item, 'r')
                TextInCurrentFile = CurrentFile.read()
                print TextInCurrentFile     # Printing textfiles content.
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

First thing is that it doesn't sort the files correctly. I would prefer it in both numerical and alphabetical number.

But my main concern is how to define define: (X0, Y0, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3)

Would it be possible to read from another file with the same file-name, located in another folder to include in the calculation. I'm going to make some comparison of each file and logging the overall results.

Comment: You can store the coordinates as a list of tuples.

Comment: By the way, the way to define a literal `set` is with `{'.txt', '.TXT'}`. However, I'd recommend getting rid of that and using `if fileType.lower() == '.txt'` instead of `if fileType in filt`.

Comment: `if item.lower().endswith(".txt")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this problem by steps. The first steps is actually getting the required files in order. I like to use glob module, but if you want your match to be case insensitive you will be better of using re module. Sorting can then be done by sorted function.

```
import os
import re
import fnmatch

rule = re.compile(fnmatch.translate('*.txt'), re.IGNORECASE) 
print sorted([fname for fname in os.listdir('.') if rule.match(fname)])
```

Now, because the data format is fixed, you can approach this by simply using a list of namedtuple to contain the data. The code could look something like this:

```
import os
import re
import fnmatch
import collections

coords_t = collections.namedtuple('coords_t', ['x0', 'y0', 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'])
data_collection = []

rule = re.compile(fnmatch.translate('*.txt'), re.IGNORECASE)
for fname in sorted([name for name in os.listdir('.') if rule.match(name)]):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        data_collection.append(coords_t(*data.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')[:-1]))

print data_collection
```

Now, you have the data saved as a list of namedtuple in the data_collection variable and you can do the required calculations. Also, it is better to use `with` context manager to work with files as it handles possible exceptions for you.

It also depends on the resulting format you want to achieve, for example if you wanted to know coordinates associated with a file dictionary would be better choice than list, using

```
{fname: coords_t(*data.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')[:-1])}
```

Usage of namedtuple gives you "nice" access to it's values, using dot notation such as `data_collection[0].x0`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. It seem like something that would work for me. I get some error on line 13. 
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 9 arguments (5 given)

I've just started using Python and I'm not familiar with how to 'split' works. 
**data_collection.append(coords_t(*data.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')[:-1]))**

Comment: It seems that you're using different newlines than \n - try replacing data.replace('\n', ' ') with data.replace('\r\n', ' ').

Comment: Could it be that I have "quad-space" (tabbed space) between the numbers? Would it work adding another ' .replace(' ',' ')'

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the overlook! data_collection.append(coords_t(*data.replace('\r\n', '    ').split('   ')[:-1])) should do the work. EDIT: the spacing is apparently broken, use 4 spaces in the replace and split arguments.

Comment: I really appreciate you help. When using:
'data_collection.append(coords_t(*data.replace('\n', '<quadspace>').split('<quadspace>')[:-1]))'

I get: 'TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 9 arguments (7 given) ' which is the closest I get. I also tried to replace the spaces with '\n' and split by '\n'. Then I also get (7 given).

Comment: It will be way simpler just using data_collection.append(coords_t(*data.split())) - if it still fails, it is possible inconsistency in the file structure.

Comment: I've figured out why your code didn't work for me. I've looked over my auto-generated data and there was one file that had only 3 coordinates instead of 4.